# How to Deploy Reports from one server to another server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i deployed the Reports which i developed in local to DEV Reporting server ( i have the credentials to  deploy in DEV).

Now i want to generate the scripts which i deployed in DEV . Using Reporting services scripter tool generated the Windows command file but when i am double click on that it is always pointing to DEV server but i want to deploy in PRODUCTION server....

please advice me...............

Comment: I found the solution.....
its just edit the windows command file and replace DEV server name with Production server name then save it and double click.
Note: whose going to double click that user should have access